# Create a list of Hex value in python

Tags: python, list, hex, pyserial

I'm working with pySerial library to read some byte from Serial Port.

I need to store these bytes into a list, but I would store data in Hex format because the serial peripheral send to me specific command code like 0x10, 0x30, ...

The code:

```
readByte = serialCOM.read(1)
print 'Read Payload byte:' + str(readByte)
packetPayload.append(readByte)
```

creates a list of char.

Which is the way to create a list of hex values?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you figure out that you have a list of chars? If you are printing it, python justs decodes these bytes to ASCII symbols while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, hex values are just an alternate view of integers:

```
>>> 1 == 0x01
True
>>> 16 == 0x10
True
```

So, here is a list:

```
>>> print([0x10, 0x20])
[16, 32]
```

It's also possible to use the `int` function to get integer value from a string:

```
>>> int('0x10', 16)  # here, the 16 is for the base, and 0x is optionnal
16
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!